# Same Neo4j query does not work in with jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

Playing around on my `Neo4j` on my localhost, I constructed this query to toggle the node property 'Active' between 'true' and 'false'

I works fine when executed in the browser but when I put it in my java class using JDBC the result is none.

```
String query = "MATCH (i:Item) "
             + "WHERE id(i)=? "
             + "SET i.active = NOT i.active";

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setInt(1, id);

int updates = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Turns out it does work but it seems that the return value i still 0.

Comment: can you specify which version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be changed as follows. You should define parameters in {}

```
String query = "MATCH (i:Item) "
                + "WHERE id(i)= {1} "
                + "SET i.active = NOT i.active";
```

Since you are not return anything you are getting return value as 0. executeUpdate()  return either  the row count for statement or 0 for statements that return nothing.

Comment: I tried it but it makes no difference. I do use ? for all other queries in the class.